# Xaml Grid Wows Text Box not appearing

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to use grid system as suggestion by another user to another question of mine I have tried to implement the grid system but with little success it is placing the buttons and the grid where i want them but the textbox for name and with should be at the bottom of the listview

[image]

These three controls should appear at the bottom of the list view

```
<TextBox   Name="txtDsiplayName" Text="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsDisplayName, Mode=TwoWay}"   Height="23"   
Width="452" Margin="0,149.86,0,188.5"    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
<Label Content="Width:" Height="400" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="452"   />
<TextBox  Name="txtWdith"   Width ="30"   Height="23" Margin="211,149.86,6,188.5" Grid.Row="1"   />
```

What am I doing wrong?

But as you see the text box is not showing correctly and the list view should be aligned to the top of the move up button winforms I forgive thee and still love ya.

```
<Grid Margin="0,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="400">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Custom Fields" Margin="12,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Label>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Expander Margin="0,0,0,0" 
          IsExpanded="true" 
            Header="Custom Columns">
            <Grid Margin="12,0,10,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="38.64" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="361.36"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="400"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="400"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="247" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="205"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ListView    Name="listView1"
            MinHeight="80" 
            SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,11.36,0,108.4" SelectionChanged="listView1_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Order" Width="100" 
                       DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsOrder}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Display Name" Width="290" 
                          DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsDisplayName}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Width" Width="50" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsWidth}"></GridViewColumn>

                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>

                <Label Content="Name:" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />

                <TextBox   Name="txtDsiplayName" Text="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsDisplayName, Mode=TwoWay}"   Height="23"   
            Width="452" Margin="0,149.86,0,188.5"    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
                <Label Content="Width:" Height="400" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="452"   />
                <TextBox  Name="txtWdith"   Width ="30"   Height="23" Margin="211,149.86,6,188.5" Grid.Row="1"   />

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,74,0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Button Name="moveUpButton"     Click="MoveUp"     DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Move Up" 
            Height="22" Width="74"  />

                    <Button Name="moveDownButton"   Click="MoveDown"    DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Move Down" 
            Height="22" Width="74"  />


                    <Button Name="deleteButton" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=columnsList, Path=SelectedItems.Count}" Click="RemoveColumn"   DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Delete" 
            Height="22" Width="74"  />

                    <Button Name="addButton" Click="AddColumn"       Content="Add Item" 
            Height="22" Width="74" />

                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the grid row height and the text box margin are conflicting with each other, if you remove the margin line from the text box you should see it moves to the top.

I would suggest removing the margins and just try to make use of heights to position the controls.

Something like this maybe? (You will need to add back in your heights/widths etc, but it gives you a rough idea)

```
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Custom Fields" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Expander Header="Custom Columns" IsExpanded="true">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ListView Name="listView1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" SelectionMode="Single">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsOrder}" Header="Order" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsDisplayName}" Header="Display Name" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsWidth}" Header="Width" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="3">
                    <Button Name="moveUpButton" Content="Move Up" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />

                    <Button Name="moveDownButton" Content="Move Down" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />

                    <Button Name="deleteButton" Content="Delete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=columnsList, Path=SelectedItems.Count}" />

                    <Button Name="addButton" Content="Add Item" />
                </StackPanel>

                <Label Grid.Row="3"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       Content="Name:" />
                <TextBox Name="txtDsiplayName" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsDisplayName, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                <Label Grid.Row="4"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       Content="Width:" />
                <TextBox Name="txtWdith" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

            </Grid>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```